# Does it make sense to migrate from Drupal + Ubercart to a platform like OpenCart or Magento?

Tags: drupal, magento, opencart

If a e-com website is running on Drupal + Ubercart does it makes sense to migrate it to a e-com suited platform like Opencart or Magento ?
Making e-com related changes to Ubercart are very combursome .. things like a customized checkout or a backend management is quite difficult..
Can any one with experience in both Drupal + Ubercart to a platform like OpenCart or Magento  help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All ecommerce requires a backend of some sort.

The latest Drupal Commerce Kickstart 2.0 is aiming to be very easy to use - more so that drupal itself. and it has some really nice features.

http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart

I would suggest you wait a week or two before using in earnest - they are improving on it very quickly in time for a big event next week.

Comment: Hi .. I checked out Drupal Commerce.. It does look very promising .. thanks for this info .. Lets see if someone else adds on new insights

Comment: Drpal Commerce shall work on Drupal 7 + .. that again brings me back to the problems of up gradation ..

Comment: Well there is that - but it sounds as if you are looking to change to a new platform. I would suggest moving from Drupal 6 to 7 is easier than moving to a different platform altogether. Check the documentation: http://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade/6/7

Answer (score 2):

If `Ubercart` is difficult for you, then `Magento` will be far more difficult.

Magento is booming in eCommerce market but it requires lots of resources and very good skill to make/customize things. If you are ready for big challenges, you should migrate your site to Magento. Considering future of Magento, it's very safe.

Comment: Thanks... How would you rate OpenCart vs Magento.. From initial digging OpenCart looks far more simpler, this makes me question how secure it is ..

Comment: There are many things proving Magento is better than Opencart when it comes to features/SEO/customization. Customization is not easy in Magento, but you can customize anything you need as it is configuration-based framework. Remember, Magento is not simple, it's tough. Depending on features you want in your website you should take decision. Check this for thorough comparison: http://www.orangecollarmedia.com/magento-vs-opencart

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely move away from Drupal eCommerce it is not built entirely for eCommerce and never will be. Both Magento and Opencart would be better options because both communities around them are entirely focused on eCommerce.  Magento is much better if you can find a good magento developer to customize it for you but Opencart is easier to use.

If you are serious about your eCommerce site than Magento is the best solution available but will come at a higher up front cost than Opencart.  However if you need a lot of advanced customization than it will actually be easier and cheaper to build in Magento down the road because advanced customization can become more difficult in Opencart because it is not built for enterprise level customization, whereas Magento is.  Magento may become easier to do things like selling at different prices to different customers (wholesale) so it really depends on the features you will need in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it makes sense to migrate from drupal to Opencart. Drupal is a CMS offering some plugins for eCommerce (and each have certain drawbacks or bugs that need to be fixed) Opencart is a platform developed for ecommerce purposes.

If compared to Magento, Opencart is also open source, functional, with large community, supports multiple languages and currencies, and what's more - allows multistore management as Magento.

On the other side - Opencart is lightweight, easier in administration, has more available documentation, and doesn't require much modifications, so you can literally start immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. i did tried opencart for analysis purpose but i found it too easily crackable.. it might b an easy solution but it isn't a safe one .. i would recommend drupal for its robustness and a strong backing from drupal community ..